# How to display BlackOil in Petrel Function Window programatically

Tags: ocean, petrel

How do you display the Oil/Water/Gas components of a BlackOil domain object programatically on the FunctionWindow?  I tried calling FunctionWindow.ShowObject on BlackOil.OilPhase but received an error that it could not be found on the input tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to say sorry here, but this is the bad case when you can get an programmatically access to the object via FluidFunctionCollection (you can create/update it), but you cannot get access to the same object via InputTree interface (you will receive an UnknownEntity via GetType method when try to navigate from Petrel UI to this object type and send it to your plug-in (doesn't exposed for Ocean from this site yet)), and by this reason you cannot display this object programmatically. I submitted an internal ticket for your case.